# AJAX improvement for validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

SO i have this piece of AJAX that work as it should be but i want to add some validation to it.I dont want it to send empty information.The AJAX is done for a comment system.It takes the value from the form and then with php it inserts it to the databse. The Problem i am haveing is that it just insert empty comment to the database

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once("menu.php");
?>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script  src="comments.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm()
            {
                var comment = document.getElementsByName('comment').value;

                if (comment == "" ) 
                {
                    alert("Please fill in all the fields");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        </script>
<?php

    $connection = connectToMySQL();


    $selectPostQuery = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblposts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$selectPostQuery)
        or die("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $postid = $row['ID'];

?>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="titlecontainer">
        <h1><?php echo $row['Title']?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="textcontainer">
        <?php echo $row['Content']?>
        </div>
<?php
        if (!empty($row['ImagePath'])) #This will check if there is an path in the textfield
        {
?>
            <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img src="images/<?php echo "$row[ImagePath]"; ?>" alt="Article Image">
            </div>
<?php
        }
?>
        <div class="timestampcontainer">
        <b>Date posted :</b><?php echo $row['TimeStamp']?>
        <b>Author :</b> Admin
        </div>
<?php
        #Selecting comments corresponding to the post
        $selectCommentQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tblcomments` LEFT JOIN `tblusers` ON tblcomments.userID = tblusers.ID WHERE tblcomments.PostID ='$postid'";

        $commentResult = mysqli_query($connection,$selectCommentQuery)
            or die ("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

        #renderinf the comments

        echo '<div class="comment-block_' . $postid .'">';

        while ($commentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentResult)) 
        {
?>
            <div class="commentcontainer">
            <div class="commentusername"><h1>Username :<?php echo $commentRow['Username']?></h1></div>
            <div class="commentcontent"><?php echo $commentRow['Content']?></div>
            <div class="commenttimestamp"><?php echo $commentRow['Timestamp']?></div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
?>
        </div>
<?php 

        if (!empty($_SESSION['userID']) ) 
        {
?>
            <form method="POST" class="post-frm" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
            <label>New Comment</label>
            <textarea name="comment" class="comment"> </textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $postid ?>">
            <input type="submit" name ="submit" class="submitComment"/>
            </form>
<?php
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<br /> <br /><br />"; 
    }
 require_once("footer.php") ?>
```

My AJAX code.I have tried to do some validation but it doesnt work properly and i dont know what is wrong with it.I am quite new to AJAX so not rlealy able to debug it myself.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click','.submitComment',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //send ajax request
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var comment = $('.comment');
        if (!comment.val()){
                alert('You need to write a comment!');       
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_comment.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(form).serialize(), //form serialize data
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //Changeing submit button value text and disableing it
                    $(this).val('Submiting ....').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var item = $(data.html).hide().fadeIn(800);
                    $('.comment-block_' + data.id).append(item);

                    // reset form and button
                    $(form).trigger('reset');
                    $(this).val('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My php code to insert into the database.

```
 <?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])):

    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    $connection = connectToMySQL();

        $userId = $_SESSION['userID'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $postId = $_POST['postid'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $date_format = " Y-m-d  g : i : s";
        $time = date ($date_format);


          $insertCommentQuery = "INSERT INTO `tblcomments` 
                                 (`Content`,`UserID`,`PostID`,`Timestamp`) 
                                VALUES (
                                   '$comment','$userId','$postId',
                                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
          $result = mysqli_query($connection,$insertCommentQuery);

$obj = array();

$obj['id'] = $postId;
$obj['html'] = '<div class="commentcontainer">
                    <div class="commentusername"><h1> Username :'.$username.'</h1></div>
                    <div class="commentcontent">'.$comment.'</div>
                    <div class="commenttimestamp">'.$time.'</div>
               </div>';
echo json_encode($obj);

    connectToMySQL(0);
   endif?>
```

Comment: what is your problem now? empty values inserting into the DB? do you have any errors in developer tools window

Comment: A yes, sorry it just insert empty comments and no errors in the consoles what so ever.

Comment: try alert the comment value,whether you are getting the empty values or not

Comment: all it gives me is [object][Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the function `validateForm()`

And this part

```
if (!comment.val()){
                alert('You need to write a comment!');       
        }
```

will always pass if there is a input field with the class `comment`, even if it's empty. You could do something like:

```
//send ajax request
if(validateForm()===false){
    alert('You need to write a comment!');
    return false;
    }
    else{
     ....
```

Comment: Take it step by step then. First put an alert at the beginning of `validateForm()` to see if it is triggered. Then place two alerts in your `if ... else ...` construction to see what it is returning: true or false

Comment: Tried that, it always returns true, for some reason no idea why.

Comment: The reason for this because when i press send the comment in the javascript its value is undefined.wheni ts empty and when it is filled with text aswell.But when i have text it works fine meaning it put the text in a comment normaly. Is it Maybe because i have multiple forms with the same name(I am view a form for each post) dont know why would that effect it tho

Comment: Then change it in `if(typeof comment=='undefined' || comment== "" )`

Comment: Ok I have fixed it! GetelementsbyName doesnt work for some reason but getElementById works like a charm.Wierd...Do you know the reason for this? and i have tierd your way aswell.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns a list of elements. It doesn't have a property `.value`. If you want to use it use document.getElementsByName('comment')[0].value. But your better of using `document.getElementById`.

Comment: One last tip: if you want to use jquery to select the element by id, you can use `$('#comment')`

Comment: Ahh ok i understand now cause i removed the id because of the html validator they where giveing an error od duplication :) and yes i know tht jquery tip thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the comment.val() to comment.text() since you are using a textarea and see if that solves your problem. The change is to be modified in your js code

Comment: When i do 
alert(comment.text());
It give an empty popup box even when i have text writen in the text box